# Are graph visualisation algorithm questions in the scope of cstheory.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

I'm looking for the most suitable place to ask a question about an algorithm for layouting a mixed constituency/dependency tree. Theoretical Computer Science seemed a good starting point, as it has a great number of algorithm questions, but I'm not sure whether Computational Science beta (http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) might be the better option, seeing that I'm looking for a graph *drawing* algorithm (to be used for visualisation) rather than a graph algorithm.

What are your opinions?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think typically asking for software/implementation is off-topic here, the scope is research-level questions in TCS as explained in the [FAQ] and questions asking for software/implementation do not fall in this scope. (However there can be exceptional question asking for software when the question it is related to research in TCS and fall inside the scope of cstheory.)

Comment: Thanks, Kaveh. I'll refrain from asking the question, and instead review the FAQs again :).

Comment: Hi again, I re-read your comment just now. In fact I wouldn't ask for software/implementation, but for a graph drawing algorithm. I'll edit my question to reflect this better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're asking about graph drawing, that's certainly within scope. Graph drawing is a rich subcommunity at the intersection of graph theory and computational geometry.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this would be about graph drawing, and more specifically an algorithm.

Comment: Yup. Definitely post it.

Comment: Thanks, will do!

Comment: Done. I really do hope [the question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11861/is-there-a-suitable-algorithm-to-draw-a-mixed-constituency-dependency-graph-in-a) is suitable.